# Route is ignored by windows

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

Windows 10 seems to ignore the new route I added.
Here is the command I used:

```
route ADD -p 192.168.2.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.14 metric 2 if 20
```

I see it in the route table:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...f0 d4 e2 f3 e2 0d ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
 19...94 e6 f7 4c 28 f0 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
  8...96 e6 f7 4c 28 ef ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #7
 20...94 e6 f7 4c 28 ef ......Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
  4...94 e6 f7 4c 28 f3 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.11     50
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.11    306
     192.168.1.11  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    306
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.1.14     192.168.1.11     52
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.11    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.1.14       2
===========================================================================
```

But When I route trace:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert 192.168.2.235

Tracing route to 192.168.2.235 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I get nothing, It will not use the gateway I added.

Thanks for the help,

Eli

Comment: How do you know from that traceroute output that the route wasn't _used_, and not just that the gateway didn't respond? 2) If you look at the packets using Wireshark, can you confirm that they're being sent to the correct (or wrong) gateway's destination MAC address?

Comment: If I remeber correctly, trace route will say the gateway its using, since its not writing noting, it uses the on-link default, and not my gateway.

Comment: No, that's not what it says. Traceroute doesn't show the "next" gateway that you're sending packets to – traceroute shows gateways that _report themselves_ after they receive the packet. Even if the correct gateway receives the packet, but doesn't respond back, it won't show up in traceroute.

Comment: Thanks, I will check using wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

The rule worked.
as @user1686 suggested, I tested with wireshark with and without the rule.
and with the rule it goes to the correct router.
For some reason that router does not know how to fw the ping request to the correct machine, but this is another problem...

Eli